# Build native 64bit and 32bit exe with JXCore

Tags: node.js, native, jxcore

I'm looking for a way to builn a native 32bit exe on my 64bit developing machine.

Usually I would run: jx compile .\PhotoFly.jxp
But that produces a 64bit version.

Any ideas how to get the 32bit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a native 32bit app on 64bit platform, you should use jx compiled for ia32 processor.

If this is on Windows, you can either use the **Windows Setup (x32/x64/SM/V8)** (on x64 Windows you will have an option to install x32 JXcore binaries as well) or download the exact binary e.g. **Windows 32 (V8)** - all available on JXcore [download](http://jxcore.com/downloads/) page.

Then you can pack the app on 64bit Windows as usual:

```
> c:\path_to_jx_32\jx compile .\PhotoFly.jxp
```

Comment: This works.... But it does not take in the jpx settings... Name, Version etc. are ignored...

Comment: Ok... It works with the .ver file in the same dir as the bin.

Comment: Do you mean you own .ver file?

Comment: Nope.. In this case, I just copied the one included.